# AS3 bitmapdata mix two alphachannels based on third alpha channel

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have three BitmapData objects, all with alpha channel.

bitmapData 1 & 2 have the same RGB content, but different alpha channels:

```
bitmapData1.rgb == bitmapData2.rgb
bitmapData1.a != bitmapData2.a
```

bitmapData 3 has completely different data.

what I want to achieve is the following:

```
targetBitmapData.rgb = bitmapData1.rgb;
targetBitmapData.a = bitmapData1.a * bitmapData3.a + bitmapData2.a*(1-bitmapData3.a);
```

so, I want to blend the alpha channels of bitmapData 1 & 2 based on alpha channel of bitmapData 3

do I need to iterate over all pixels to do this, or is there a faster way? experimented with copyPixels, but didn't get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this with multiple [`draw`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw%28%29) operations using [`BlendMode`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BlendMode.html).  It may require too many operations to be more efficient than iteration.

If you end up iterating pixels (and aren't targeting iOS), consider [PixelBender](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pixelbender.html).